# Range of values of parameter $\gamma$ in perturbation matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, condition-number

I have an orthogonal matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{10^{5}\times 10^{5}}$ and a perturbation matrix $\delta A = \epsilon A, \epsilon = 10^{-16}.$How can I calculate the range of values of parameter $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that the relative perturbation error to be less than $10^{-7}$?.Given that $||b||_{2}=1$ and $\delta b = [\epsilon,0,\dots,0,\epsilon]^{T}$ and $$\frac{||x + \delta x ||}{ ||x||} \leq \frac{1+\gamma K(A)}{1- \gamma K(A)} $$

where $K(A) = ||A|| * ||A^{-1}||$.

Comment: If $A$ is orthogonal then $\kappa(A) =1$ which makes your right hand $\frac{1 + \gamma}{1 - \gamma}  $. That is if you're using the 2-norm.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm missing something here but supposing $\kappa_{2}(A) = \|A \|_{2}\|A^{-1}\|_{2}$  and $A$ is orthogonal then $\kappa_{2}(A) = 1$ and your formula becomes

$$ \frac{1+\gamma}{1-\gamma} $$

Now you should realize the left-hand side is non-negative since $\frac{\| x + \delta x \|}{\|x\|}$ is strictly positive since $\| x\|$ can't be $0$. In that case we know that it's $0$ when $\gamma = -1$ and undefined when $\gamma = 1$. If you solve from when the expression is equal we have

$$ \frac{1+\gamma}{1-\gamma} = 10^{-7} $$

we get

$$ (1+\gamma)(10000000) = 1-\gamma  $$

$$ 10000001\gamma = -9999999  \implies \gamma  = \frac{-9999999}{10000001}$$

So the values that work are where $\gamma \in (-1, \frac{-9999999}{10000001})$.

Comment: it can’t be.Because $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

Comment: @Mr.Podilatis Where does it say that? If $\gamma$ is only positive there is no solution. $\frac{1+\gamma}{1-\gamma} \leq 10^{-7}$ also works for $\gamma > 1$ but then that expression is negative and the lower bound of the relative error is strictly positive.